# Tensorflow: Expected bool, got 1 of type 'int' instead

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

My problem is when I try to calculate the loss value I got the following error:

> Expected bool, got 1 of type 'int' instead.

My objective is try to recognize a character in a image, but not all images have a character. So, the label of each image is composed by a value (0 or 1) indicating the presence or not of a character followed by a one-hot vector indicating the corresponding character (A->Z->0->9). For example I have a image containing the 'B' character the label is like that:

1 0100000000000000000000000000000000000

If the image do not contain any character at all, the one-hot character is random, for example:

0 0000000000000000010000000000000000000

To calculate the loss I am using sigmoid for the first value of the label and softmax for the character part. But in images who do not have a character I want to "ignore" the softmax part. I tried to do this:

```
def loss_total(logits_value):
    is_char = tf_train_labels[:, 0] > 0.5

    logits_part_1 = logits_value[:, 0]
    logits_part_2 = logits_value[is_char, 1:]

    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits_part_1, labels=tf_train_labels[:,0]))
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits_part_2, labels=tf_train_labels[is_char,1:])) + loss
...
```

I create a random batch of 50 images and tried to train the CNN. The first line of the function is to calculate which of the 50 images are characters. Then I tried to divide the labels.
I take all the 50 images to calculate the sigmoid loss and try to take all the character images to calculate the softmax loss but when I do that the described error appears.

> logits_part_2 = logits_value[is_char, 1:] -> Expected bool, got 1 of type 'int' instead.

In numpy I think that would worked, but not using Tensors unfortunately. Someone knows how I can fix that?

Comment: what are all your parameters mean an what are there expected values/types?

Comment: @SalvadorDali 'logits_value' is the exit of the CNN without the activation function applied (Tensor with shape [50, 37]), 'tf_train_labels' is the ground truth for each label (shape[50, 37] too). And 'is_char' is a vector of size 50 indicating True (there is a character) or False (random image) for each of the rows of the training batch. The expected value/type for 'logits_parts_2' is a Tensor with shape[where_is_true_in_the_vector_'is_char', 36] and dtype=float.